# Single File Upload - Flash (swf)

Tags: upload, flash

Is it possible to upload files to a server, with flash only? I'm looking for a SWF file that's able to do this task. So my question is:

- is it possible to upload a file with flash alone (no PHP or ASP)
- in case this is possible: is there a simple SWF-file to do this task which I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to upload a file with flash alone (no PHP or ASP)

Of course not - how will the server know what to do with the file if there's no server side script?

> in case this is possible: is there a simple SWF-file to do this task which I could use?

In general, you'll also need JavaScript (and somewhere to post the file to, so some server-side script).

This one is a self-contained solution: http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Otherwise, this jQuery plugin is quite good: http://www.uploadify.com/